# Generate ESRI grid with xllcenter/yllcenter in header

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, 3d-analyst, esri-ascii-raster

I'm trying to generate ARC/INFO ASCII GRID (*.asc) from point feature class using `Create TIN` - `TIN to raster` - `Raster to ASCII` functions. I'm looking for a way to have the output raster file header referring to center of left lower pixel instead of corner. (xllcenter/yllcenter instead of xllcorner/yllcorner).

Is there a way to get this type of header directly from ArcGIS? If not - is it correct if I just rewrite the header from corner to center and change the coordinates to coordinates of center of the left lower pixel (as shown below)?

This is the header from `Raster to ASCII` tool:

```
ncols 1000
nrows 1000
xllcorner 1271000
yllcorner 7269000
cellsize 5.0000
```

This is the header I need:

```
ncols 1000
nrows 1000
xllcenter 1271002.500
yllcenter 7269002.500
cellsize 5.0000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An .asc file is also known as [ESRI ASCII Raster](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/gp_toolref/spatial_analyst_tools/esri_ascii_raster_format.htm) format. The file header takes both xllcenter or xllcorner (and yllcenter or yllcorner) arguments, which represent the X coordinate of the origin by center or lower left corner of the cell, respectively.

And you are correct, it is not possible to output with xllcenter and yllcenter. The [Raster to ASCII](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/raster-to-ascii.htm) tool help says:

> This tool **only** writes the origin as the lower left corner of the lower left cell.

Therefore, the solution is to alter the header the way you've suggested:

```
ncols 1000
nrows 1000
xllcenter 1271002.500
yllcenter 7269002.500
cellsize 5.0000
```